# Como faço para fazer busca em diferente documentos e subdocumentos mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Queria fazer um *find* em uma tela de *login* em que ele verificasse tanto no campo *login* do documento e *login* do subdocumento. Tem como fazer isso?

```
{
 Login: admin,
Senha : 12345,
_id : 73h2b2k18bdjd88,
Nivel : 1
Usuarios [
    { 
       Login : andre,
      Senha : 17344,
     _id : 73b3hjd8did,
    Nivel : 2
   }
]
}
```

Comment: se poder postar os subdocumentos fica melhor para poder ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu vi no exemplo os `_id` não tem um vinculo:
Se tiver vinculo pode fazer um *lookup* na *collection* `Usuario` no lugar no project, eu fiz em cima do resultado que você colocou como exemplo

Você pode fazer assim:

```
db.login.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        'Login': 'admin',
        'Senha': '12345',
    }
},
{
    $project :{
        login: db.login.distinct('Usuarios.Login', { 'Usuarios.Login': 'andre' }),
        senha: db.login.distinct('Usuarios.Senha', { 'Usuarios.Login': 'andre' }),    
    }
},
{ $unwind: { 'path': '$login', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': false } },
{ $unwind: { 'path': '$senha', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': false } },
{
    $match: {
        'login': 'andre',
        'senha': '17344',
    }
}
])
```